# Python binary data reading

Tags: python, binary-data

A urllib2 request receives binary response as below:

```
00 00 00 01 00 04 41 4D 54 44 00 00 00 00 02 41
97 33 33 41 99 5C 29 41 90 3D 71 41 91 D7 0A 47
0F C6 14 00 00 01 16 6A E0 68 80 41 93 B4 05 41
97 1E B8 41 90 7A E1 41 96 8F 57 46 E6 2E 80 00
00 01 16 7A 53 7C 80 FF FF
```

Its structure is:

```
DATA, TYPE, DESCRIPTION
 
00 00 00 01, 4 bytes, Symbol Count =1
 
00 04, 2 bytes, Symbol Length = 4
 
41 4D 54 44, 6 bytes, Symbol = AMTD
 
00, 1 byte, Error code = 0 (OK)
 
00 00 00 02, 4 bytes, Bar Count =  2
 
FIRST BAR
 
41 97 33 33, 4 bytes, Close = 18.90
 
41 99 5C 29, 4 bytes, High = 19.17
 
41 90 3D 71, 4 bytes, Low = 18.03
 
41 91 D7 0A, 4 bytes, Open = 18.23
 
47 0F C6 14, 4 bytes, Volume = 3,680,608
 
00 00 01 16 6A E0 68 80, 8 bytes, Timestamp = November 23,2007
 
SECOND BAR
 
41 93 B4 05, 4 bytes, Close = 18.4629
 
41 97 1E B8, 4 bytes, High = 18.89
 
41 90 7A E1, 4 bytes, Low = 18.06
 
41 96 8F 57, 4 bytes, Open = 18.82
 
46 E6 2E 80, 4 bytes, Volume = 2,946,325
 
00 00 01 16 7A 53 7C 80, 8 bytes, Timestamp = November 26,2007
 
TERMINATOR
 
FF FF, 2 bytes,
```

How to read binary data like this?

Thanks in advance.

#### Update:

I tried struct module on first 6 bytes with following code:

```
struct.unpack('ih', response.read(6))
```

(16777216, 1024)

But it should output (1, 4). I take a look at the manual but have no clue what was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> data
'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x04AMTD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02A\x9733A\x99\\)A\x90=qA\x91\xd7\nG\x0f\xc6\x14\x00\x00\x01\x16j\xe0h\x80A\x93\xb4\x05A\x97\x1e\xb8A\x90z\xe1A\x96\x8fWF\xe6.\x80\x00\x00\x01\x16zS|\x80\xff\xff'
>>> from struct import unpack, calcsize
>>> scount, slength = unpack("!IH", data[:6])
>>> assert scount == 1
>>> symbol, error_code = unpack("!%dsb" % slength, data[6:6+slength+1])
>>> assert error_code == 0
>>> symbol
'AMTD'
>>> bar_count = unpack("!I", data[6+slength+1:6+slength+1+4])
>>> bar_count
(2,)
>>> bar_format = "!5fQ"                                                         
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Bar = namedtuple("Bar", "Close High Low Open Volume Timestamp")             
>>> b = Bar(*unpack(bar_format, data[6+slength+1+4:6+slength+1+4+calcsize(bar_format)]))
>>> b
Bar(Close=18.899999618530273, High=19.170000076293945, Low=18.030000686645508, Open=18.229999542236328, Volume=36806.078125, Timestamp=1195794000000L)
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(b.Timestamp//1000)
'Fri Nov 23 08:00:00 2007'
>>> int(b.Volume*100 + 0.5)
3680608
```

Answer (score 10):

So here's my best shot at interpreting the data you're giving...:

```
import datetime
import struct

class Printable(object):
  specials = ()
  def __str__(self):
    resultlines = []
    for pair in self.__dict__.items():
      if pair[0] in self.specials: continue
      resultlines.append('%10s %s' % pair)
    return '\n'.join(resultlines)

head_fmt = '>IH6sBH'
head_struct = struct.Struct(head_fmt)
class Header(Printable):
  specials = ('bars',)
  def __init__(self, symbol_count, symbol_length,
               symbol, error_code, bar_count):
    self.__dict__.update(locals())
    self.bars = []
    del self.self

bar_fmt = '>5fQ'
bar_struct = struct.Struct(bar_fmt)
class Bar(Printable):
  specials = ('header',)
  def __init__(self, header, close, high, low,
               open, volume, timestamp):
    self.__dict__.update(locals())
    self.header.bars.append(self)
    del self.self
    self.timestamp /= 1000.0
    self.timestamp = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(self.timestamp)

def showdata(data):
  terminator = '\xff' * 2
  assert data[-2:] == terminator
  head_data = head_struct.unpack(data[:head_struct.size])
  try:
    assert head_data[4] * bar_struct.size + head_struct.size == \
           len(data) - len(terminator)
  except AssertionError:
    print 'data length is %d' % len(data)
    print 'head struct size is %d' % head_struct.size
    print 'bar struct size is %d' % bar_struct.size
    print 'number of bars is %d' % head_data[4]
    print 'head data:', head_data
    print 'terminator:', terminator
    print 'so, something is wrong, since',
    print head_data[4] * bar_struct.size + head_struct.size, '!=',
    print len(data) - len(terminator)
    raise

  head = Header(*head_data)
  for i in range(head.bar_count):
    bar_substr = data[head_struct.size + i * bar_struct.size:
                      head_struct.size + (i+1) * bar_struct.size]
    bar_data = bar_struct.unpack(bar_substr)
    Bar(head, *bar_data)
  assert len(head.bars) == head.bar_count
  print head
  for i, x in enumerate(head.bars):
    print 'Bar #%s' % i
    print x

datas = '''
00 00 00 01 00 04 41 4D 54 44 00 00 00 00 02 41
97 33 33 41 99 5C 29 41 90 3D 71 41 91 D7 0A 47
0F C6 14 00 00 01 16 6A E0 68 80 41 93 B4 05 41
97 1E B8 41 90 7A E1 41 96 8F 57 46 E6 2E 80 00
00 01 16 7A 53 7C 80 FF FF
'''

data = ''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in datas.split())
showdata(data)
```

this emits:

```
symbol_count 1
 bar_count 2
    symbol AMTD
error_code 0
symbol_length 4
Bar #0
    volume 36806.078125
 timestamp 2007-11-22
      high 19.1700000763
       low 18.0300006866
     close 18.8999996185
      open 18.2299995422
Bar #1
    volume 29463.25
 timestamp 2007-11-25
      high 18.8899993896
       low 18.0599994659
     close 18.4629001617
      open 18.8199901581
```

...which seems to be pretty close to what you want, net of some output formatting details.  Hope this helps!-)

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> >>> struct.unpack('ih', response.read(6))
> (16777216, 1024)
> ```

You are unpacking big-endian data on a little-endian machine. Try this instead:

```
>>> struct.unpack('!IH', response.read(6))
(1L, 4)
```

This tells unpack to consider the data in network-order (big-endian). Also, the values of counts and lengths can not be negative, so you should should use the unsigned variants in your format string.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [struct.unpack](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?#struct.unpack) in the struct module.

Answer (score 1):

Use pack/unpack functions from "struct" package. More info here http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Bye!

Comment: Hi,

I tried struct module on first 6 bytes with following code:

>>> struct.unpack('ih', response.read(6))
(16777216, 1024)

But it should output (1, 4). Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Jack

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned, `struct` is the module you need to use.

Please read its documentation to learn about byte ordering, etc.

In your example you need to do the following (as your data is big-endian and unsigned):

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = '\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x04'
>>> struct.unpack('>IH', x)
(1, 4)
```