# How do I convert a base 10 float to hex in Python 2.4?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, python-2.4

I trying to convert numbers from decimal to hex. How do I convert `float` values to hex or char in Python 2.4.3?

I would then like to be able to print it as ("\xa5\x (new hex number here)"). How do I do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/python-convert-hex-to-float

Comment: Do you want the binary representation of the IEEE float in hex, do you just want the integer portion in hex, or do you want the whole thing in hex?

Comment: Hi, what's your use for this? Are you trying to keep decimal precision if you print/read the number? You might want to look at decimal floating point for this, it's a lot more portable and you won't end up with an angry mob at your gate with torches and pitchforks.

Answer (score 1):

From python 2.6.5 [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) in hex(x) definition:

To obtain a hexadecimal string representation for a float, use the float.hex() method.

Comment: would you mind please to give an example of its use?
I am trying to convert this 0.554 to hex by using float.hex(value)?  and how can I write it as (\x30\x30\x35\x35)?

Comment: In this case you could have written it as 0.554.hex().  But the result would have been wildly different than what you're expecting.  see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex

Comment: I realize that what the OP actually wants is the Hex values for the ASCII codes of the numbers. I am not editing my answer as Jeremy already gave a solution below. In any case the hint given by jordan 0.554 == '\x30\x30\x35\x35' was also wrong as the decimal point was not indicated and actually '\x30\x30\x35\x35' == '0055'.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this comment:

> would you mind please to give an
>   example of its use? I am trying to
>   convert this 0.554 to hex by using
>   float.hex(value)? and how can I write
>   it as (\x30\x30\x35\x35)? – jordan2010
>   1 hour ago

what you really want is a hexadecimal representation of the ASCII codes of those numerical characters rather than an actual float represented in hex.

"5" = 53(base 10) = 0x35 (base 16)

You can use ord() to get the ASCII code for each character like this:

```
>>> [ ord(char) for char in "0.554" ]
[48, 46, 53, 53, 52]
```

Do you want a human-readable representation?  hex() will give you one but it is not in the same format that you asked for:

```
>>> [ hex(ord(char)) for char in "0.554" ]
['0x30', '0x2e', '0x35', '0x35', '0x34']
#   0      .        5       5       4
```

Instead you can use string substitution and appropriate formatters

```
res = "".join( [ "\\x%02X" % ord(char) for char in "0.554" ] )
>>> print res
\x30\x2E\x35\x35\x34
```

But if you want to serialize the data, look into using the `struct` module to pack the data into buffers.

**edited to answer jordan2010's second comment**

Here's a quick addition to pad the number with leading zeroes.

```
>>> padded_integer_str = "%04d" % 5
>>> print padded_integer_str
0005
>>> res = "".join( [ "\\x%02X" % ord(char) for char in padded_integer_str] )
>>> print res
\x30\x30\x30\x35
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting for an explanation on string formatters

Comment: That is lovely, thanks for this.
I packet the data, but I am wondering if I can remove \x2E from \x30\x2E\x35\x35\x34

Comment: i got it, but if I tried to find for 5 i am unable to represent it in this form \x30\x30\x30\x35

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a float directly to hex. You need to convert to int first.

```
hex(int(value))
```

Note that int always rounds down, so you might want to do the rounding explicitly before converting to int:

```
hex(int(round(value)))
```

Comment: Yes, understood, but how can I do this; I converted the hex to decimal. However, my problem is to convert this float decimal numbers to hex in python

For example: 
The hexadecimal for 0.26 is \x30\x32\x36\x36, how this can be done in Python?

Comment: What do you mean, converted it to decimal? Can you give an example of what you've done? Representing decimal numbers can be done a bunch of different ways, so it would be helpful if you could describe it in some detail (or provide some code).