# Hex string to floating point conversion in python mismatching with IEEE-754 value

Tags: python, floating-point, hex, data-conversion, ieee-754

In Python, I need to convert a string to float where the string hex value as below

```
print(float.fromhex("c018dd8dad51d100"))
```

I got a value of:

> 1.3842057055291167e+19

but the same string in IEEE-754 calculator given some other negative value. My requirement is to match with IEEE-754 standard. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: What is exactly the other value that you are getting from the calculator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float)

Answer (score 4):

`float.fromhex` doesn't do what you think it does.

You can use `binascii.unhexlify` to convert from hex to bytes and then `struct.unpack` to convert from 8 IEEE-754 bytes to a double (it seems that your representation is big endian, so I've added `>`):

```
import binascii
import struct

# "d" is for double, > is for big endian, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html
value, = struct.unpack('>d', binascii.unhexlify(b'c018dd8dad51d100'))
```

Comment: Its working. Awesome. Thanks.