# Convert hex string to float

Tags: python, casting, hex, idl-programming-language

I am trying to read from a file a bunch of hex numbers.

```
lines ='4005297103CE40C040059B532A7472C440061509BB9597D7400696DBCF1E35CC4007206BB5B0A67B4007AF4B08111B87400840D4766460524008D47E0FFB4ABA400969A572EBAFE7400A0107CCFDF50E'
dummy = [lines[index][i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(lines[index]),16)]
rdummy=[]
for elem in dummy[:-1]:
 
                rdummy.append(int(elem,16))
```

these are 10 number of 16 digits
in particular when reading the first one, I have:

```
print(dummy[0])
4005297103CE40C0
```

now I would like to convert it to float

I have an IDL script that when reading this number gives 2.64523509

the command used in IDL is

```
double(4613138958682833088,0)
```

where it appers 0 is an offset used when converting.

is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: `int('4005297103CE40C0', base=16)`

Comment: Your problem should be solved by the answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float)

Comment: none of the proposed links help.

Comment: as I said, I know the result of the conversion (2.645)

Comment: I don't see how a 16-digit hex number can give a float value of 2.6.  Something else is going on.

Comment: int('4005297103CE40C0', base=16) yields 4613138958682833088. now if I go on my IDL console and I cast to double---> double(4613138958682833088,0) = 2.6452350899999999. I just want to understand how to do this last casting in pYthon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to use the `struct` package for this, something like this seems to work:

```py
import struct

lines ='4005297103CE40C040059B532A7472C440061509BB9597D7400696DBCF1E35CC4007206BB5B0A67B4007AF4B08111B87400840D4766460524008D47E0FFB4ABA400969A572EBAFE7400A0107CCFDF50E'

for [value] in struct.iter_unpack('>d', bytes.fromhex(lines)):
  print(value)
```

results in `2.64523509` being printed first which seems about right