# how to convert a hex number to float in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, modbus

how to convert a hex number to float
i use this in C

```
HexTofloat float (uint32_t x){
   return (* (float *) & x);
}
i = HexTofloat (1130839281);
print (i); //result 231.24
```

How does it work? i want to make it in python

Comment: is this answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1592158

Answer (score 0):

You must use `float.fromhex` and `float.hex`

```
float.fromhex('0x1.5c28f5c28f5c3p-1')
Output: 0.68
```

Comment: I have tried it by entering the value '1130839281' but the result is not 231.24

float.fromhex('1130839281')
Output: 73828373121.0

Answer (score 0):

you can use in-built function of python like this : `float.hex(num)`

Comment: I have tried it by entering the value '1130839281' but the result is not 231.24

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library which is known as `ast` 
To install this library you need to type:- `pip install AST`
eg:-

```
from ast import literal_eval 
data = "0xAB15"
out = literal_eval(data) 
print(out)
```

you will get the output:- `43797`