# Python program to convert Hexadecimal to IEEE-754 Floating Point with Single precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, hex, ieee-754

I'm writing a Python program to decode Base64(Raw Data) output from my sensors to find it's latitude and longitude.

After checking the documents (attached below) that came with the sensor to decode the values, I'm still unsure on how to achieve it. I found a partial solution to convert it below but not sure how to achieve the final output.

So for example, if the Hexa value is `B4 39 F5 42`, my latitude output should be `1.3768`.

[image]

```
import binascii
import struct


data = 'F9 7B 9C 45'
fdata = struct.unpack('<f', binascii.unhexlify(data.replace(' ', '')))[0]
print(fdata)
```

output:

```
5007.49658203125
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float)

Comment: Hi @PacketLoss, I tried the first two answers it doesn't seem to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You should now convert the floating point number to degrees as specified in the docs you attached:

```
deg = fdata // 100 + (fdata % 100) / 60
```

The result would be `50.124943033854166` for `'F9 7B 9C 45'` and `1.3768783569335938` for `'B4 39 F5 42'`.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk. Got the desired output.