# ctypes cast() returning nan when casting an int pointer to a float pointer

Tags: python, numpy, casting, double, ctypes

I'm reading in a binary file and need to interpret the data as a bunch of different data types.
I'm doing this with a mixture of numpy and ctypes.

One of the conversions I need to do is from 4 uint16 values to an IEEE 754 double.

I'm combining the uints like this:

```
   fval = np.uint64((np.int64(uint16_arr[0]) << 48) | (np.int64(uint16_arr[1]) << 32)) | (uint16_arr[2] << 16) | (uint16_arr[3])
```

and converting them to the double using some code I found in another answer like this:

```
   fval = convert_64(fval)

def convert_64(s): # converts doubles
    cp = pointer(c_uint64(s)) # make this into a 64 bit c integer
    fp = cast(cp, POINTER(c_double)) # cast the int pointer to a float pointer
    return fp.contents.value # dereference the pointer, get the float
    # function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float
```

This works great for everything but one set of data: [C0 84] [84 B6] [B8 F9] [B1 31]

For some reason cast() returns nan for this. I've confirmed via prints that the value is making it all the way to the cp variable, but for some reason the cast() isn't working to get it to the fp variable.
All of the other data I need to convert to doubles goes through just fine and comes out with the correct value. It's just this one set that's giving me problems.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected result of your sample data? `struct.unpack('>d',bytes.fromhex('C0 84 84 B6 B8 F9 B1 31'))[0]` -> `-656.58922`,

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**:

- As seen in comments, you might want to use [[Python.Docs]: struct - Interpret strings as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct), as it's more straightforward. *CTypes* requires some pointer knowledge
- Don't know what you're trying to pull here, but reinterpretting *uint64* as *double* doesn't seem such a good idea (because of different representations), and a perfectly valid *uint64* might yield *NaN*
- Couldn't reproduce your behavior

  - All the examples except the one *@Base* annotated, are to test various endianness variants

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


def ui2d(ui):
    #cp = ct.pointer(ct.c_uint64(ui))  # Same thing in 2 steps
    #return ct.cast(cp, ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)).contents.value
    return ct.cast(ct.pointer(ct.c_uint64(ui)), ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)).contents.value


def print_ui(ui):
    print("0x{:016X} {:d} {:.6f} {:.6f}".format(ui, ui, ui, ui2d(ui)))


def main(*argv):
    s0 = "C08484B6B8F9B131"
    s1 = "84C0B684F9B831B1"
    print_ui(int(s0, 16))  # @Base
    print_ui(int(s0[::-1], 16))  # Reverse
    print_ui(int(s1, 16))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q068821063]> ${PY_VENVS_HOME}/py_pc064_03_08_test0/bin/python code00.py 
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> 0xC08484B6B8F9B131 13872358672530256177 13872358672530255872.000000 -656.589220
> 0x131B9F8B6B48480C 1376869532240988172 1376869532240988160.000000 0.000000
> 0x84C0B684F9B831B1 9565846290776469937 9565846290776469504.000000 -0.000000
> ```

Comment: Thanks for you're response! I agree that re-interpreting the data as a double could be problematic. However it's test data that should always be a double, just in a binary file that has a bunch of different data types I have to sort out.
I did finally find the problem. It was with the bit shifting I was doing to create the number I was passing in. I'm not sure why, but when I altered my code to combine the 4 unit16s as a hex string, then converted the hex string to an integer, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem! it was with the way I was combining the uint16s.
When I did it as a concatenated string of hex values, everything worked fine.
I replaced this line:

```
fval = np.uint64((np.int64(uint16_arr[0]) << 48) | (np.int64(uint16_arr[1]) << 32)) | (uint16_arr[2] << 16) | (uint16_arr[3])
```

with this:

```
fval = "{MSB:04X}{MID_HI:04X}{MID_LOW:04X}{LSB:04X}".format(MSB = uint16_arr[0],MID_HI = uint16_arr[1],MID_LOW = uint16_arr[2],LSB = uint16_arr[3])
```

Then I added this to the beginning of my conversion function:

```
 def convert_64(s): # converts doubles
    i = int(s, 16)  # convert from hex to a python int
    cp = pointer(c_uint64(i)) # make this into a 64 bit c integer
```

This made it work for my problem data set. I have no idea why the bit shifting didn't work, but it was the problem.
Thanks everyone for your help!